# Html: 2 td's, how to align them center?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

below is the code for Submit and Cancel button. When i have 3 buttons, i aligned the middle one as center. So all the 3 buttons looked good on center. But for something like this, with 2 buttons. How can i align them in the center of tr. With this code it shows on bit left side. Thanks!!

```
<tr align="center">

    <td style="width: 100px; height: 45px;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSubmit" runat="server" 
             ImageUrl="~/images/submitnew.gif"
             OnClick="imgbtnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="valCC" 
             TabIndex="21" />
    </td>

    <td style="width: 100px; height: 45px;">
          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel2" runat="server" 
              ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif"
              OnClick="imgbtnCancel2_Click" CausesValidation="false" 
              ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
              ValidationGroup="valCC" />
    </td>
```

Comment: How many TDs are in the other TRs in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in one cell (with `colspan=2`) and center them there:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px; height: 45px; text-align: center;" colspan=2>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSubmit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/submitnew.gif"
             OnClick="imgbtnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="valCC" TabIndex="21" />
          <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif"
              OnClick="imgbtnCancel2_Click" CausesValidation="false" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
              ValidationGroup="valCC" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You assign hard widths to both cells. That should force them to the left.  If you want things centered, best to leave the sizes off and let the browser figure out what size is best.

Further, Using tables for formating a rookie mistake, as it usually ends up with problems like you're having.  Try:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <asp:ImageButton ..... />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:ImageButton ..... />

</div>
```

Comment: @Ram Much better to use tableless layout for HTML structure.